# Анонимные мстители на SO

Tags: дефект, предложение, репутация, голоса-против

Постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем что пользователи SO мстят одним нехитрым способом. Просто берут и голосуют против всех вопросов жертвы. Неужели нельзя поставить таймаут на дело?

Comment: Конкретнее будьте любезны.

Comment: если конкретней то посмотрите мои первые ~100 ответов, все проминусованы одним и тем же человеком в течении получаса. сегодня с последними одиннадцатью вопрос/ответами та же ситуация, что человека на этой цифре остановило не знаю. обиженцы думают что минус в их вопросе я поставил, ну и мстят таким образом. я когда еще на hashcode был мне минус тыщу приписали и здесь то же самое.

Comment: ...там, правда, обсуждается ситуация с плюсами, но это не принципиально. С минусами просто знаки дельт другие, вот и вся разница.

Comment: **tl;dr**: не парьтесь, система сама в течение суток откатит этот выброс эмоций.

Comment: @ АлексейШиманский вы не поверите но там плюсы были и разницу вы видимо не видите сейчас. так же учитывайте что минусы не только в вопросах но и в ответах. я конечно не требую проверки. но думаю к таймауту нужно трехдневный бан прицепить

Comment: Понимаю вас, но с другой стороны голосование - дело добровольное, если за это наказывать, куда будет смотреть демократия?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian . не совсем понимаете. какой смысл очки набирать если один недовольный человек несправедливо всю карму отъедает. он что пуп земли?

Comment: @perfect вы вообще прочитали вопросы, к которым ваш только что задубликатили?

Comment: Ну, отъедает то гораздо меньше минус чем дает плюс. Т.е. один такой плохиш при всем желании не испортит вам репу. Да и что вам эта репа дает, у вас уже вполне достаточная для всех основных плюшек.

Comment: Посмотрел я ваши заминусованные вопросы-ответы. Кстати в бОльшей части я б тоже минусанул б. Потому что три или четыре (не помню точно) вопроса не отвечают форматам ruSO. то есть предполагают ответы, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях.... и парочка ответов сомнительные

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , если хотите конкретики. тогда слушайте. в общем человек мне говорит: если ты такой умный то пройди тест на моем сайте (это наш участник). в итоге я написал скрипт который отвечает на его тест за доли секунды. после работы моего скрипта его сайт упал. он пришел и понаставил мне минусов. теперь вопрос к вам: я заслужил это?

Comment: Дайте ссылку, интересно тоже пройти тест.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian если найду сейчас скину

Comment: @VladimirGamalian и создать тему `соревнование`: напиши тест, который убивает сайт быстрее других :)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian не могу найти давно это было. админ быстрей меня это найдет. помоему в первом вопросе минусатора я вместо ответа на его вопрос ответ на его тест в виде скриншота приложил. ник его не помню. аватарка чувак в галстуке но это не Pavel Mayorov(то же наш старый участник)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а сама задача вот эта была https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @perfect это я-то ваш старый участник? :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov предпологаю вам год, могу конечно ошибаться. или вам от этого плохо? )

Comment: Всего минусанули 11 вопросов подряд. Из низ 2 - дважды. Такое серийное минусование откатится автоматически.

Comment: @Nofate, я понял. просто гадал почему история не развилась по старому сценарию. просто глюк из хэшкода который плавно перетек на SO всегда напоминает о себе. но я бы за такое действие недолгим баном наградил.

Comment: @perfect Если система автоматически не откатит вредительские голоса, пожалуйста, дайте знать мне в чате. Я пройдусь в ручном режиме.